# session.run() give different results for same input

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I'm loading a tensorflow Saved  Model and try to infer with loaded model.

It takes a gray image as input and outputs a gray image of the same size.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img_width=224
img_height=224

export_path='/path/to/my/saved/model'
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.Graph()) as sess:
  # Load model
  tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], export_path)

  # Load test image (grayscale)
  path = '/path/to/test/images/image.png'
  img = Image.open(path)
  img.show()
  img_data = np.array(img).reshape(1,img_width,img_height,1)

  # Infer output
  y_pred = sess.run('output:0', feed_dict={'input:0': img_data })
  print(y_pred.shape)

  # Show output image
  im1 = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(y_pred.reshape(img_width,img_height)*255), 'L')
  im1.show()

  # Infer output
  y_pred = sess.run('output:0', feed_dict={'input:0': img_data })

  # Show output image
  im2 = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(y_pred.reshape(img_width,img_height)*255), 'L')
  im2.show()
```

Running this simple code, I got 2 different results. Im1 not exactly the same as Im2.

Am I doing something wrong ?

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not using the right way to reload de TF21 saved model.